# I am looking for building instructions for the Megabloks Viking Ship 9604

Tags: instructions, clone-brands

I have parts of the Megabloks set 9604 Viking Ship but can not find the building instructions for it. The goal is to be able to complete this set.

Answer (score 3):

***BOOM***!

[image]

Found them free online ***[HERE](http://bloksforum.freeforums.net/thread/264/9604-viking-ship)***.